# Draw two subgraphs together with intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to produce a molecular graph like this
[image]

But I'm not sure how to achieve this by `subgraph`, I have the following tikz code

```tex
    \tikz \graph [nodes={fill, circle, inner sep=2pt}, empty nodes] {
        {
            subgraph C_n [clockwise, n=6, name=A];
            subgraph C_n [clockwise, n=6, name=B];
        };
    };
```

which simply produces half of the desired figure

[image]

but I have no clue how to complete the other half.

Comment: Does a *molecular graph* have something to do with chemistry or math? If the former, there might be better approaches than the `graphs` library, for example the [`chemfig` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Ah yeah indeed I will have to type some chemistry, thanks for the recommendation! But just out of curiosity too, I also wonder how to make this particular graph work with `tikz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to actually have 6 + 6 nodes but 6 + 4 which is why I'm only going to use `n = 4` at the second subgraph. But since you want them placed like they are part of 6 nodes we use `clockwise = 6` which adjusts the angle accordingly.

Since the `circular placement` rules start at the top by default this all we need to place the additional in the correct placement relative to each other.

However, you want the second set of nodes to be placed to the right which I will realize with `xshift`ing the whole subgraph about the length between the hexagons' centers.

The `P_n` subgraph doesn't connect the first and last node compared to `C_n`.

The connection to the left set of nodes will be made manually.
In this example, I have these edges red and directed to highlight these for this answer. Simply remove `[red]` and replace `->` with `--` to have them appear as all the other edges.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [nodes={fill, circle, inner sep=2pt}, empty nodes] {
  subgraph C_n [clockwise, n=6, name=A];
  subgraph P_n [
    /tikz/xshift=2*cos(30)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/graphs/radius},
    clockwise=6, n=4, name=B];
  {A 2, A 3} ->[red] {B 1, B 4};
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! And huge thanks for the understandable comments!